# Variable x equals a or b

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation

Is this:

```
if(x == a || b){//do something}
```

same as:

```
if(x == a || x == b){//do something}
```

?

I think it is not, because in the first case we evaluate if x equals a and if b is true or false.

In the second case, we evaluate if x equals a and if x equals b. And I understand that in the [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) if x equals a than we are not evaluating further.

But somebody thinks that in the first case we ask if x equals a or b, so I wanna make sure.

Comment: `"I think it is not"` - you are correct and so is your reasoning.

Comment: It's easier to test this yourself than to ask a question about it.

Comment: @Nile A test tells you how one implementation does it once. Consulting the standard (or Stack Overflow) tells you how every implementation ought to behave.

Comment: Probably a good idea to right code that in the first inspection requires one to scratch ones head.

Comment: C or C++? Don't tag both.

Comment: Ok, I have removed C tag.

Comment: Whats wrong with this question?

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

In C++, this:

```
x == a || b  // Same as (x == a) || b
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(x == a) || (bool)b
```

Which evaluates to `true` if `x` and `a` are equal OR if `b` evaluates to `true` when converted to `bool`. In C, on the other hand, it is equivalent to this:

```
(x == a) || (b != 0)
```

Which evaluate to `true` if `x` and `a` are equal OR if `b` is different from 0 (here we must make the implicit assumption that `b` is of integral type, otherwise this won't compile).

On the other hand, this:

```
(x == a || x == b) // Same as ((x == a) || (x == b))
```

Evaluates to `true` when either `x` and `a` are equal OR `x` and `b` are equal (i.e., if `x` is either equal to `a` or equal to `b`) both in C++ and in C.

Comment: ehh not quite, C doesn't have a bool type and I don't think C++ diverts from C in this construct. Of course OP tagged as both so it's a bit of a free for all.

Comment: @djechlin: Right, I missed the C tag. This answer is for C++. I will edit.

Comment: I'm still not sure it's correct though?  I don't know if C++ does `if(5)` means `if((bool) 5)` or `if(true)` means `if((int)true)`.  The latter makes less sense but is more consistent with C.

Comment: @djechlin: In C++ the condition in `if` is converted to `bool`. See Paragraph 6.4/4 of the C++11 Standard: "*The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch statement is the value of the declared variable contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4). If that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.*"

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions are not equivalent. This

```
if(x == a || b)
```

is the equivalent of

```
if( (x == a) || (b))
```

i.e an OR of `x==a` and `b`. In C++, if `b` evaluates to anything other than `0` or `false`, it is taken as `true`.

The second one tests whether `x==b` instead of simply testing `b`.

Answer (score 1):

No. In C this is equivalent to:

```
if(x == a || b != 0)
```

Comment: `b` is not necessarily comparable to `0` though.

Comment: are there warnings that can be generated by `b != 0` but not `b`?

Comment: @djechlin no, because this is really equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The first reads as "if x is equal to a, or if b is truthy"

The second reads as "if x is equal to a, or if x is equal to b"

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

```
if (x == a || b)
```

is equal to

```
if ((x == a) || (bool)b)
```

because operator `==` has higher *precedence* than operator `||`.  See [Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, the first case means *x equals a OR b is true*.

Lazy evaluation means that the expression will be evaluated only until the result is obvious. In an OR expression, for example `(x || y)`, the result will be known when `x==true` – then the whole expression must be true too. In the case of AND, like `(x && y)`, the result will be evident when `x==false`. So you are right, if `x==a`, we know the answer already and no more work is needed.