# Checking if value equals either a or b

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to have the user be able to control when they want to exit the while loop, and also i was wondering on how to exit the program when done

```
    cout<<"Play again? (Y/N)"<<endl;
char userInput;
cin>>userInput;
if (userInput='y'|'Y')
{
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore();
   input();
   userInput=0;
}


else

{
    exit(0);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15052737/1270789 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/151850/1270789 (Also, there's no `while` loop)

Comment: `userInput='y'|'Y'`: That's not how conditional expressions work.

Comment: See also [which-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-with-conditional-if-statements-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959876/which-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-with-conditional-if-statements-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `userInput='y'|'Y'` suffers from three fundamental problems and a compounding problem.

1. `'y'|'Y'` is not a logical OR operation. It is a bitwise OR operation.
2. It does not compare the value of `userInput` against `'y'` or `'Y'`.
3. It assigns the value of the subexpression `'y'|'Y'`, which evaluates to the integral value 121 in a system that uses ASCII encoding, to `userInput`.
4. As a consequence, the conditional of the `if` statement always evaluates to `true`.

What you need is:

```
if ( userInput == 'y' || userInput == 'Y' )
```